# 2 img src, one image is displayed and the other doesn't

Tags: html

In html programming class I tried to make an html file and display two images. For any reason me and my teacher can't determine, there is one image which isn't being displayed.

Could you please let me know why this is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img scr="https://www.sublimetext.com/images/windows_48.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp.png"></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have misspelled `src`, you have `scr`

it should be `<img src="https://www.sublimetext.com/images/windows_48.png" />`